# Checking for valid type input using std::cin (C++)

Tags: c++, cin

I am working on the game 'Hex' for a C++ class, and am having trouble understanding how to make sure cin is reading the correct type.  I have done some research and I'm close, but here is my problem:

```
    int i, j;
    while(true){
        cin >> i;
        if(cin.fail() ){ //if type wasn't right
            cin.clear(); //clear stream
            cin.ignore(); //ignore left over data
            cout << "First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to " << size - 1 << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cin >> j;
        if(cin.fail() ){ //if type wasn't right
            cin.clear(); //clear stream
            cin.ignore(); //ignore left over data
            cout << "Second value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to " << size - 1 << endl;
            continue;
        }
        if(i < 0 or i >= size or j < 0 or j >= size){
            //prompt that input is wrong
            cout << "Invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to " << size - 1 << endl;
            continue;
        }
```

There are break statements there, it does get out okay.  My problem is with runs such as this:

```
Player 1's turn
Enter the row and column coordinate with only a space inbetween
a b
First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10
First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10
u 8
First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10
8 u
```

It doesn't detect that the second value was incorrect when they both were, and when only the second is incorrect, it doesn't detect it as an error.  I have looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/?kw=cin and it doesn't even have the documentation for the fail, clear, and ignore functions, so I don't fully understand them.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're ignoring a single character and restarting your loop, so after any error you're back at the "first" value.  `cin >>` works a whitespace-delimited word at a time, with a newline being just another whitespace character.

Comment: The documentation isn't there because those are methods of the class `std::istream`, of which `cin` is an instance. Try this link instead : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/.

Comment: But I write my own test code, finding that the second could be detected. Check your code if  `while()` is broke out.`int z;
  int s;
  std::cin >> z;
  if(std::cin.fail())
  {
   printf("first cin is failed!\n");
  }
  std::cin >> s;
  if(std::cin.fail())
  {
   printf("second cin is failed!\n");
  }` @user2309865

Comment: By the by, if you want to avoid the second `First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10` line from appearing, you might want to use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead of `cin.ignore();`. This will ignore the rest of the line in the `cin` input stream after the first failure. This might be more elegant. You'll need to include the header `<limits>`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
u 8
First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10
8 u
```

As `cin >> i;` fails because of `u`, the loop is repeated, but only the first character following in the `cin` stream, a space, is consumed by `cin.ignore();`. As the loop starts again, `cin >> i;` is executed using what's left in the stream, in this case `8`. This means that after the error message `First value is invalid input! Valid coordinates are in range 0 to 10`, the program is actually waiting on `cin >> j;`. When `8 u` is entered, it reads `8` first and assigns its value to j, meaning there is no failure. The loop ends, and `u` is left in the stream.

To fix this, change `cin.ignore();` by `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. Instead of ignoring only the next character, which is a space in this example, it'll ignore the rest of the line, effectively resetting the `cin` stream. You'll need to include the `<limits>` header.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thanks a ton for explaining this!