# Checking if input is a number and treating it as char otherwise

Tags: c++, cin

My problem is with this fragment of code:

```
     int number;
     char character;

     cin >> number;

     if(!cin) {
         //input is not a number 
         cin.clear();
         cin.sync();
         cin >> character;
         //other stuff...
     }else{
         //input is a number
         //other stuff...
     }
```

Basically, I want to check if the next input is a number and if not, treat it like a char. The problem is that as you can see my code checks if the input is a number and if not, treats the NEXT input as char.

Could you tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Also note that i cannot use strings.

Comment: You should have a look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726657/checking-for-valid-type-input-using-stdcin-c and use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`.

Answer (score 2):

Read input as a string, try to convert it to a number using [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) and if it fails treat the input as a character.

Comment: is there any other way? I am not allowed to use strings

Comment: @Simon look at atol()

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a char then check using is_digit. Another approach would be to read an entire line into a char array buffer using getline and then go through the char array somehow. I could elaborate more on that.

Comment: what about numbers >10?

Comment: Ok My answer works only if read character by character it is a special case. It is not your solution then. I might then delete this answer?

Comment: Weird question I know,  but did you just come back from doing your laundry?

Comment: @Me myself and I: I guess that the likelihood ought to be high based on which day it is combined with my posted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example given at this place:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear

It basically does what you ask for, and it basically does it the same way as you've attempted. (Just, there is no call to [`std::cin.sync()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sync), which probably just does nothing for stdin anyway.)

Note that, when the extraction fails, the bytes are left in the buffer. You can perfectly extract them by a later `std::cin >> c`. That is, from my understanding, the problem you've described does not exist.

Here is the code from above linked page (added comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    double n;
    // try to extract a number from stdin repeatedly
    while( std::cout << "Please, enter a number\n"
           && ! (std::cin >> n) )
    {
        // extraction failed, clear failbit
        std::cin.clear();
        // extract another thing instead, here: a string
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        // do something with that string
        std::cout << "I am sorry, but '" << line << "' is not a number\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Thank you for entering the number " << n << '\n';
}
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt