# Program seems to be skipping second set of inputs and going directly to the end calculations

Tags: c++

after the second output statement, the program doesn't take the second set of inputs. Any idea what I could even do to fix this? Is this just a quirk of C++?
Any help at all is much appreciated. :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int startHours, startMinutes;
    int endHours, endMinutes;
    bool startIsAM, endIsAM;
    char amPmChar, extra;

    
    
    int computeDifference(int startH, int startM, bool startTime, int endH, int endM, bool endTime);

    int diff, hours, minutes;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------//

    cout << "Enter start time, in the format 'HH:MM xm', where 'xm' is\n either 'am' or 'pm' for AM or PM: ";
    cin >> startHours;
    cin >> extra;
    cin >> startMinutes;
    cin >> amPmChar;

    startIsAM = (amPmChar == 'A') || (amPmChar == 'a');

    cout << "Enter future time in the format 'HH:MM xm' where 'xm' is\n either 'am' or 'pm': ";
    cin >> endHours;
    cin >> extra;
    cin >> endMinutes;
    cin >> amPmChar;
}
```

Comment: If the issue is the "second cout", why post all of the code after it?  Please cut down your code to a [mcve].  By your description [this code would cause the same issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08fb2f8945f2300a)

Comment: Note the users who aren't entering typos are probably entering malicious inputs for fun or profit. Always check the stream to make sure you got input and then check the input to make sure it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read one more char, because when you read amPmChar from the input - m is still in your stream. And after that - there is an endline, so your endHours tries to initialize with that value. That's your problem.
You may read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726657/checking-for-valid-type-input-using-stdcin-c) answer, it's about cin validation.